# Facebook login with spring-security

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-security

I am trying to add facebook login to my Spring project. I am able to add the user to the database but I still need to authenticate him with my Spring security. Does anybody know how to do this or do you know a good tutorial?

FBLogin.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function postFunction(type, username, typeUsername, firstname, lastname, id){
    $.post(location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/ProjectTeamF-     1.0/user/addSocial.html', {
        type:type,
        userName:username,
        typeUserName:typeUsername,
        firstName:firstname,
        lastName:lastname,
        id:id
    }, function (data) {

        window.location = "http://localhost:8080/ProjectTeamF-1.0/" + data;
    });
}

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
    login();
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
    logout();
});

function login() {
    var fbFirstName;
    var fbLastName;
    var fbId;
    var fbUserName;
    var fbScreenName;

    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        if (response.username == null) {
            fbScreenName = response.first_name + response.last_name;
            fbUserName = response.first_name + response.last_name;
        } else {
            fbScreenName = response.username;
            fbUserName = response.username;
        }
        fbFirstName = response.first_name;
        fbLastName = response.last_name;
        fbId = response.id;
        postFunction('Facebook',fbUserName, fbScreenName, fbFirstName, fbLastName, fbId);
    });


}

function logout() {

}
```

})

AddSocialUser method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/addSocial", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
String addSocialContact(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    User user = new User();

    if (userService.findUser(request.getParameter("userName")) == null) {
        user.setUsername(request.getParameter("userName"));
        user.setPassword(request.getParameter("id"));
        user.setFirstName((request.getParameter("firstName")));
        user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));

        userService.addUser(user);


    } else {
        user = userService.findUser(request.getParameter("userName"));
    }

   List<GrantedAuthority> gaList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    gaList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User usersec = new  org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, gaList);
    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usersec, user.getPassword(), gaList);
    org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext sc = new SecurityContextImpl();
    sc.setAuthentication(auth);
    org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.setContext(sc);

    return "/ProjectTeamF-1.0/j_spring_security_check";
}
```

Edit:
This is our spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/admincp-*.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/TripParticipants/*.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/editUserequipment/*.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/TripCategorie/*.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/StopPlaats/*.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/trip/join/*.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/trip/addTrip.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/general/login.html" default-target-url="/general/index.html"
                authentication-failure-url="/user/loginfailed.html" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" />
</http>

<authentication-manager >
       <authentication-provider >
           <password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

          users-by-username-query="
          select username,password ,true
          from t_user where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query="
          select username, 'ROLE_USER' from t_user where username=? "/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html

Comment: If you need to call Facebook from java directly (not form JavaScript) then take a look on [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) and [Spring Social Facebook](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/) projects (but it will be more heavyweight than your current solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only authenticate your user then just do

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = new User(login, password, true, true, true, true, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext sc = new SecurityContextImpl();
sc.setAuthentication(auth);
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.setContext(sc);
```

and make sure that current and all subsequent http requests are covered by spring security filters. If all user info come from Facebook then DB user is not necessary.

Comment: How do you mean just do? I added the code to my controller but doesn't seems to help. Not al users are from facebook. You have the option to make your own user or to log in with facebook.

Comment: Adjust this code for your needs. Add missed "ROLE_USER" into each list of GrantedAuthority objects.

Comment: Still the same. I edited my code above so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: It works now. I replaced return "/ProjectTeamF-1.0/j_spring_security_check"; to return "/general/index.html";. So just back to my index and it seems to work. Thank you for your help.